# HiddenInput not working while render on view MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used **HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)** like:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
[DisplayName("Updated By")]
public string Updatedby { get; set; }
```

but it's still rendering as **EditorFor**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Updatedby, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Updatedby, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Updatedby, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to render it as hidden field. How can I do that? Thank you.

Comment: "but still rendering as EditorFor"...what do you mean exactly? You mean it still displays a textbox on the screen instead of a hidden field?

Comment: yes its displaying text box when i create view of the model with Edit template...

Comment: Can we have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, so we can understand how you're using this model, how you're creating and rendering the view etc. From the code you've shown, there's nothing obviously wrong, so we need more info. Could you even make a runnable demo of the problem via [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) maybe?? Thanks.

Comment: If you set the attribute [ScaffoldColumn(false)] on your property, does this give you the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Updatedbynew ,new { @class = "form-control" })
```

for rendering a hidden model-binded field in DOM.

Comment: thank for your answer.. but i dot want to do it manually i this it should be generated automatically when generate view by using Edit Template.